# Android Studio not stopping for asking to update Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Since the latest version, Android Studio is annoying me that

> It is strongly recommended that you update Gradle to version 2.14.1 or later.

[image]

Sadly I can´t update it currently, because it breaks my project completely and I need to do research to get it working, so I´m pressing

> "Don´t remind me again for this project"

But it ignores it and it pops up over and over again.

Is there any trick to get rid of it?

Comment: I  am seeing it as well, very annoying because my team isn't ready for upgrade yet and I had accidentally hit update couple of times.

Comment: mine was a on a mac

Comment: I clicked this button by accident and am interested in knowing how to reset the setting.

Comment: @QED Did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: @QED Figured it out! See my answer below.

Answer (score 26):

This dialog should store:

```
<component name="PropertiesComponent">
  ...  
  <property name="show.do.not.ask.upgrade.gradle.plugin.version" value="2.2.0" />
  ...
</component>
```

in your `.idea/workspace.xml` file.

As you can see it seems to be version specific, hope this helps.

**If you clicked `Don't remind me again for this project.` by accident, remove that line**