# Android studio 3.0 not prompting to update android plugin and gradle version automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am using android 3.0 canary 2 version. After importing old project into android studio once I click `sync project with gradle` android studio not prompted/suggested for updating `android plugin` and `gradle` latest version to update. No pop up is showing for the update.

Previous android studio version has this feature but android studio 3.0 not prompting this.
Is it android studio 3.0 limitation or the feature is deprecated.

Comment: For me it suggested to update the gradle plugin to 3.0.0-alpha2. But if you previously flagged "Don't ask me again for this project" in the suggested updated dialog and refused to update you will not be prompted again

Comment: To reset the setting and be prompted to update the plugin and gradle in the next project re-opening, you can follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511275/2910520)

Comment: @MatPag I never flagged "Don't ask me again for this project" for android studio 3.0

Comment: Check the link i provided to you and see if the line is there. If not this could be a bug in the latest AS canary version

Comment: i've performed some tests and it's a bug in the new version. Probably i confused the update dialog with the Canary 1 one... I've added an answer with the current state of the situation (i've added +1 to your question to cancel the nosense -1)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is a bug in AS 3.0 Canary 2, i've commented on [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62149410) published in the AS bug tracker hoping to increase visibility.

Current manual update:

**Step 1** - Add the new google maven repository to the project dependencies (only if you are updating from current stable android plugin 2.3.2 otherwise you already have it installed) and update the Android plugin to 3.0.0-alpha2.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
    }
}
```

**Step 2** - Update the `distributionUrl` of the gradle-wrapper.properties file to the latest version of Gradle (obviously for this to work you need to "use the default gradle wrapper (recommended)" option in settings).

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-rc-1-all.zip
```