# How to show Android Gradle Plugin update dialog again

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

I've updated Android Studio and the dialog for Gradle Plugin update appeared. I've accidentally clicked *Don't show again for this project*. How can I display the dialog again?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511275/2207083) you should look for a file `.idea/workspace.xml` in the project directory and remove property line below.

```
<component name="PropertiesComponent">
  ...  
  <property name="show.do.not.ask.upgrade.gradle.plugin.version" value="2.2.0" />
  ...
</component>
```

Also, it's related to a specific gradle version, so if you update it once, you'll see the dialog again the next time.

Comment: Similarly if you clicked the remind me tomorrow and want to see it again immediately, the property is : <property name="sync.plugin.last.upgrade.timestamp" value="" /> delete them, re-open the project, and the dialog should appear.

Answer (score 16):

inside the project directory open the file .idea/workspace.xml
find the line (search for upgrade word)

```
<property name="sync.plugin.last.upgrade.timestamp" value="154032093109" />
```

if you change this to a smaller integer like 15403293109 (removing one number from middle) will make the last check date to a previous time and the upgrading dialog will be visible again.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio Project, Go to

```
-> File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation
```

Here you will see "Display Options dialog when these commands are invoked".
Now enable the check box "Update". That's all.

Comment: Even tho you didn't answer this question, you answered my question, thanks!

Comment: Unchecking/checking this and then running Gradle sync really makes AS display update dialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the build.gradle file open in Android Studio, hover your mouse over the yellow text and choose "More actions..." -> "Invoke Upgrade Assistant"